# Get stock data for grouped products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grouped-products, quantity

How to get grouped product stock in Magento 2? If it uses parent product's quantity, then how can I get the default qty which is set while grouping?

Answer (score 0):

Group product is a collection of simple products in Magento2. 
Each of those products have their own stock.
https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-grouped.html

Comment: Thanks! for the reply @sphinks. I know that. But, I need to know the default quantity which is set while grouping so that I have to control them in custom APIs